# Adding cookie in java and then HTTP redirect doesnt show cookie in client side

Tags: java, cookies, redirectwithcookies

I have requirement where in i need to add cookie in java and then redirect it to different URL. Now this url process should persist the cookie which i set and after its processing send it back to client. The code goes as follows

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("name", "value")
// To make sure cookie is established for all the url paths
cookie.setPath(request.getContextPath());
response.addCookie(cookie);
response.sendRedirect("someNewUrl");
```

Please help me regarding how can i persist the cookie throughout the redirect lifecycle and to the client. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try to actually *add* the cookie to the response:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("user", "anonymous");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

See also:

- [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.addCookie(javax.servlet.http.Cookie)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addCookie%28javax.servlet.http.Cookie%29)

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake.. I did add the cookie but by mistake didnt copy the code.. So present scenario is I have added to cookie to request as well but due to redirect its getting lost somewhere. Sorry for the mistake and thanks for replying... Looking forward to get the answer soon

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the cookie to the response? 
I'm seeing the code that just creates the cookie.

Try this :

```
 Cookie c = new Cookie(name,value);
    c.setMaxAge( 3 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 );
    c.setPath( "/" );
    response.addCookie( c );
```

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake.. I did add the cookie but by mistake didnt copy the code.. So present scenario is I have added to cookie to request as well but due to redirect its getting lost somewhere. Sorry for the mistake and thanks for replying... Looking forward to get the answer soon