# How to retain session after browser close?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, tomcat

In Java EE HttpSession, when I set the session timeout to negative (by using setMaxInactiveInterval), supposedly, I thought it should be retained even after the browser is closed. But according to this page [Session Lost when closing the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693180/session-lost-when-closing-the-browser), it seems like it doesn't.

How can this happen? Then I have to use a cookie to store the session id? Then how am I going to generate this session id by myself? I will lose the HttpSession's advantage if I manage the session by myself.

I am using Tomcat in this case. How do you all settle this issue? Any simplest way in doing this?

Comment: 1. Post some code here from the filter where you're setting the cookie's lifespan. 2. Make sure your browser is allowing cookies

Comment: @kolossus I am still learning J2EE, haven't touch the filter yet. Will the session (J2EE) persist after we close the browser? Or whatever we set the timeout in setMaxInactiveInterval, session will be still destroyed if we close the browser?

Comment: So you haven't actually tested anything yet?

Comment: @GMsoF it looks like you didn't understand the answer (note that BalusC is a Java Web Application expert). If you open a web browser (chrome or firefox) and navigate to your web page, the session will start living at the time the user entered on the page and will die if **the user closes the web browser** (note: web browser, closing the tab while having other tabs won't kill the session) or **after a timeout since the last time the user made a request to the server**.

Comment: @GMsoF if you want to make the cookie live longer than the time the user closes the web browser, you can follow the advices from BalusC. It's not quite obvious for a starter, but here are some readings: [Java Servlet Filter](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info), [Adding cookie in java and then HTTP redirect doesnt show cookie in client side](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4456454/1065197).

Comment: @kolossus I have tested, the result is same what I have said. I will re-ask because I worry I did something wrong and produce incorrect result, and I have seen a lot of post asking "How to close Java session when browser close", then I wonder why they ask this? because session will be destroyed after browser close. Then I wonder will session retain after browser close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using cookies you could use a flag in the database to check whether the person has logged out or not. So you don't have to worry about the filters and the cookies

Make sure to toggle the flag once the user logs out.